# Exercise sheet with two enumerated columns

Tags: enumerate, multicol, exercises

Do you have a simple, minimal template to type Exercise sheets with exercises enumerated with two columns (please check image).

[image: Example]

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't need a template, it's quite straightforward

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that's ok. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure the numbering should not be horizontal?

Comment: @Bernard: In that case you can provide the other answer with `tasks` etc ;-)

Comment: This surely must be a duplicate question. If I am not mistaken this has been asked a few times before…

Answer (score 5):

Unless there should be no balanced heights of the `\item` in the `multicol` environment this is quite easy. The `enumitem` package isn't necessary at all, but might help for some more 'sophisticated' numbering/labeling of the items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Calculate that 
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \item D
    \item E
    \item F
    \item G
    \item H
    \item I
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\item Another question -- \blindtext
\item Yet another question -- \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, you might want to use $\displaystyle ...$ for the math expressions.  That way it will look more like \\[...\\] than $,,,$.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Which math expressions? I didn't not use any one so far.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer - That comment was intended for the OP, who presumably will be putting his expressions into your solution.

Answer (score 4):

You also can have a horizontal enumeration, which more natural, in my opinion, either with the `tasks` package, or with `shortlst`. You can choose the number of columns with the `nc` key (default is $3$) and the interlining with the `il` key, defaulting to $1$. Here is a demo of both ways:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[a]),label-width=1.5em}
\usepackage{shortlst,setspace,xkeyval}%
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,#1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{(m)}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortenumerate}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
 }%
 \newcommand\paritem[2][1]{\item \parbox[t]{#1\shortitemwidth}{\setstretch{1}#2\medskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Solve the following equations:
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task Equation $1$
 \task Equation $2$
 \task Equation $3$
 \task Equation $4$ is a rather long equation
 \task Equation $5$
 \task Equation $6$
 \task Equation $7$
 \task Equation $8$
\end{tasks}
\bigskip

\noindent Solve the following equations:
\begin{tabenumerate}
  \item Equation $1$
\item Equation $2$
\item Equation $3$
\item Equation $4$ is a rather long equation
\item Equation $5$
\paritem[1] {Equation $6$ is another long equation}
\paritem[2] {Equation $7$ is a third long equation that stretches along two columns. }
\item Equation $8$

\end{tabenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is a great solution. Thank you Bernard.