# How I do I make enumerated lists in columns (see image)

Tags: lists, enumerate, columns

How I do I make lists like the image below?  Is there a package that will do something like this automatically?  Something where I can specify the number of columns and it will space items horizontally across the page?

[image]

Comment: see and many others : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/customizing-inline-enumerate-with-enumitem-still-not-working

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You mean something like the `mtabular` environment shown in Herbert's Mathmode book in section 67.1? Here a link: <http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf#page=124>

Comment: this could help you : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/horizontal-enumeration-in-multiple-columns

Comment: `tasks` package

Comment: You have the `tasks` package or `shortlst`. See my answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273859/exercise-sheet-with-two-enumerated-columns/273918#273918)  for an example of both.

Answer (score 2):

A work around using `tabularx` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{row}
\renewcommand\therow{\alph{row}}

\newenvironment{rowenum}[1]
    {\setcounter{row}{0}
        \par\noindent\tabularx{\linewidth}[t]
        {*{#1}{>{\stepcounter{row}\makebox[1.8em][l]{\therow)\hfill}}X}}%
    }
    {\endtabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{rowenum}{3}
    $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x)$ & $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x)$ & $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x)$ \\
    $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x)$ & $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x)$ & $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x)$ \\
\end{rowenum}

\end{document}
```

The mandatory argument is the number of columns you want.

This solution is not perfect but it is a good work around.  For a more flexible solution, have a look at the `task` package, as suggested by Christian Hupfer.  I didn't have the time to try it yet, but it is promising.

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution/ workaround:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    (a) \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x) & (b) \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x) & (c)\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x) \\
    (d)\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x) & (e)\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x) & (f)\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x) \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

You can alter the number of columns in the argument of `\begin{array}` i.e. `{ccc}` gives you three columns etc. You can find more info on that [here](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Array_(LaTeX_environment)).

Comment: The explicit typing of `a)` etc. might get tedious

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to use the `tasks` package, which is dedicated to horizontal lists:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

For the function $h$ whose graph is given, state the value of each quantity, if it exists. If it does not exist, explain why.
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, label=\bfseries 1., start=6]
  \item For the function $h$ whose graph is given, state the value of each quantity, if it exists. If it does not exist, explain why.

        \begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[a]),item-indent=3em, label-offset=0.65em, ](3)%
          \task $ \lim\limits_{x \to -3^{-}} h(x) $
          \task $ \lim\limits_{x \to -3^{+}} h(x) $
          \task $ \lim\limits_{x \to -3} h(x) $
          \task $ h(-3) $
          \task $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0^{-}} h(x) $
          \task $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0^{ + }} h(x) $
          \task $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} h(x) $
          \task $h(0)$
          \task $ \lim\limits_{x \to 2} h(x) $
        \end{tasks}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]