# How to write formulas in some columns

Tags: tables

Can you help me?
How can I write this fragment in Tex?

[image: Formulas]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! one possibilities is use of `multicols` package, `itemize` and after each `item` write your equation. onother possibilities is use specialized `\documentclass`  (context of your equation is not known). for more, you should show what you try so far in form of small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303912/15925 help?

Comment: amsmath: `align`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I do I make enumerated lists in columns (see image)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303912/how-i-do-i-make-enumerated-lists-in-columns-see-image)